# Plastic bottle, how to get neck exaggerated/magnified shadows, model included

Tags: modeling, materials, shaders

I am modeling a PET bottle, and when I look at my reference, I feel like the material at the plastic neck has exaggerated/magnified shadows. Initially, I thought it must be because the plastic is thicker there, but after testing it, I don't see any significant difference.

So, I think it must be something with the material/shading, and wondering it that’s possible to re-create. I've uploaded the bottle and image reference

**Mine:**

[image: Mine]

**The references:**

[image: References]

**the model:** https://blend-exchange.com/b/oog2Mvwd

Update: I tried creating a normal map, thinking I could create "distortion"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of sharp edges shadow by detecting them.

On left your file model, on right corrected:

[image]

Here is the shader setting:

[image]

which make transparent parts that are the most along normals.

It has other effets indeed... but in my opinion, not so unrealistic.

Tune the map range values to adjust it to you needs.

Comment: Thank you for answering me! That was really usefull! I'm sorry if wasn't clear enough. But I want the exaggerated/magnified "shadows" as seen in the references here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bcpH.png

Comment: you're welcome. But ok, the reference should have different thicknesses not simply a regular solidify thickness (at least, I think). Water should matter also for the reference.